# For 2 arrays, subtract every element in one array from the position-matching element in the other

Tags: code-golf, math

For 2 arrays each with X elements, what is the SHORTEST code to subtract every element in the second from every element in the first, 1 to 1

so, for example:

A1 = [10,11,12]

A2 = [1,2,3]

A1 "-" A2 should == [9,9,9]

Comment: Come on. Code golf should have enough complexity for the competitors to exercise some creativity. Really.

Comment: dmckee: Exactly my thoughts. This one is way too trivial to make a good task (see the R solution, for example). Now if only people could stop by the Sandbox on meta before posting a task ...

Comment: Though I agree that this question is lousy for golf I find it very unfair that it has *at the same time* a negative vote count but 5 questions of +14.

Comment: GP, GAP, J, Fortran, Maxima, ... solution: "A1 - A2"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### R, 3 chars

(following Chris' counting method that includes the variable names in the count)

```
a-b
```

`a` and `b` can be defined as follows:

```
a <- c(10,11,12)
b <- c(1,2,3)
```

(`c` is the array construction function in R)

Comment: Is this the _normal way_ for defining arrays in R? and if not, what would the code be, if you have a and b already defined.

Comment: @Samer, yes that's the normal way. The code would be exactly the same. In fact, you can even do `c(10,11,12)-c(1,2,3)`. So theoretically it's only a single character.

Answer (score 7):

## J, 1 char

I will answer too because finally I don't have to use 2 bytes worth of enclosing brackets for J. :)

```
   -

   10 11 12 - 1 2 3
9 9 9
```

Answer (score 5):

### Scheme, 11 chars

Assume the lists are named `a` and `b`:

```
(map - a b)
```

Example:

```
(map - '(10 11 12) '(1 2 3))  ; => (9 9 9)
```

Answer (score 4):

### In Haskell (10):

```
zipWith(-)
```

will do the job. Please note, that the lists will be truncated, if their length isn't equal.

Comment: Well, the task states that they are of equal length *x*, so I guess that can be neglected.

Comment: Lists? Doesn't Haskell have Arrays?

Comment: @user unknown: They exists, but aren't used very often. In this case, using arrays would blow up my solution by about 30 chars.

Comment: :) That's why I'm asking. :)

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> class L(list):
...  def __sub__(self, other):
...   return map(int.__sub__,self, other)
... 
>>> a=L([10,11,12])
>>> b=L([1,2,3])
>>> a-b
[9, 9, 9]
>>>
```

Answer (score 4):

## ES6, 20

```
a.map((x,i)=>x-b[i])
```

Answer (score 3):

#### In Python (24):

```
map(lambda a,b:a-b,a,b)
```

#### Smaller (21):

```
map(int.__sub__,a,b)
```

Answer (score 2):

Groovy:

```
List a = [1,2,3]
List b=[2,7,9]
[0,1,2].each { println(a[it]-b[it]) }
```

Answer (score 2):

#### Scala, 51 chars

```
Array(10,11,12) zip Array(1,2,3)map(x=>x._1-x._2)
```

(but includes initialisation, Array-Declaration)

```
(10 to 12).zip (1 to 3)map(x=>x._1-x._2)
```

is a bit shorter, but produces an Vector.

```
a zip b.map(x=>x._1-x._2)
```

is even shorter, but of course I could do

```
a zip b.map f
```

then. Or just

```
g
```

Answer (score 2):

## CJam, 10 bytes

CJam is newer than this challenge, but I thought it's funny how uncompetitive it is for once:

```
l~]z{~-}%p
```

This is an STDIN to STDOUT program, reading input like `[10 9 8] [1 2 3]`. I know everyone else is answering in snippets, but that wouldn't really be shorter here, because you'd have to replace `]` by something like `a\a\+`.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-BASIC, 5 bytes

```
L1-L2
```

Input lists are stored in the `L1` and `L2` tokens.  (TI-BASIC doesn't have STDIN or equivalent.)
Answer is stored in `Ans`.

**Example:**

```
{10,11,12→L1
      {10 11 12}
{1,2,3→L2
         {1 2 3}
L1-L2
         {9 9 9}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not counting `USE: syntax math sequences ; !` because it's not needed (on the REPL).

Factor: `[ - ] 2map`

Comment: And... what language should that be?

Answer (score 0):

Not the shortest, but this is what I came up with in javascript...

```
t=0;
ar=[];
for(i=0;i<ar.length;i++){
   t=a[i]-b[i];
   ar.push(temp);
};
```

**Input:** a = [10,11,12], b = [1,2,3]
**Output:** [9,9,9]

Comment: You can shorten your code by removing unnecessary whitespace, using one-character variable names, and dropping the `var` keyword when creating a variable.

Comment: You're welcome! Actually, you don't need newlines and indentation in JavaScript, so you can save some more characters if you remove some whitespace and if you use `c` instead of `ar`. Also, please include the character count in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

## [8th](http://8th-dev.com/), 10 bytes

**Code**

```
' n:- a:op
```

**Explanation**

`a:op` takes two arrays and invokes the word `n:-` to the corresponding elements of "a1" and "a2", producing a new array "a3".

**Example**

```
ok> [10,11,12] [1,2,3] ' n:- a:op .
[9,9,9]
```

Comment: Note: [Non-competing is no longer a thing](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12877/58974)

Comment: @Shaggy - Thank for your comment. A new rule to learn.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 45 bytes

```java
a->b->{for(int i=0;i<a.length;a[i]-=b[i++]);}
```

Modifies the first input-array instead of returning a new one to save bytes.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##bY@xboNADIb3PIVHUOAU0pEEqarUrVNGxGAul9T0uDtxJhVCPDu9AFI7VPJgWZ/9f27wgal1yjTXr1lq9B4@kMy4A/CMTBKaQIieSYtbbySTNeJ9a05kuKyS/5A3a3zfqm5FigIknGHGtKjTYrzZLgpzoPMhpxMKrcydP3MsqUrPdUn7fRXn05wHiVCur3Xw2HQelq7QBsXowh2Ze1kBxk9dgCUKsOtwCGFGfa@TMTskWZZkxylfMCnQOT1ECxgLlFI5jv7gyTF5meIVvgyeVStsz8KFONYm@v329XnBC7arynZx2Zx20/wD)

```java
a->b->{            // Method with two integer-array parameters and no return-type
  for(int i=0;     //  Start at index 0
      i<a.length;  //  Loop over the input arrays by index
    a[i]-=b[i++]   //   Modify array `a` by subtracting the values of `b` on the same index
  );               //  End of loop
}                  // End of method
```

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 29 bytes

I got creative with I/O types for this. It's a lambda (curried) from an ordered `IntStream` (A1) to a lambda from a mutable `List<Integer>` (implementing `remove(int)`, e.g. `ArrayList`) (A2) to `IntStream`. Assign to `Function<IntStream, Function<List<Integer>, IntStream>>`.

```java
s->l->s.map(n->n-l.remove(0))
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##jZFLa8MwEITPya/YowS2aJse0jwMpVAotOSQ3koPiqMEubJktGuXEPzbXdlxyYtCbws7841mlclKxq5QNlt/NUW5MjqF1EhEeJPawn44KLyuJClAkhSWWTCIkrQRm9KmpJ0Vz/0wO@6QvJK5eLG07Kbon75XjTQLLrVVPjk1XQKTBLBckZcpwbzBODFxgiKXBbNxYmMjvMpdpdgN581gOgw1Dt36FpXTa8hDQxZw2m4/PkH6LfK28ODvVECYnzzq0Xu5w17FrPoGbSmg9qMIxhGM7iN4qPn0DHnWEEzgtb4L5pmIXQVKbAVdYC9qQ28jiO8iCKHjmnepyx2SyoUrSYRftGQs@z2akEVhdgx5PxjeHu/dLVYZ65mTSSVNqRYbLlJnjEqJXV3m6bBwHgW57lG8i66HdfMD)

Yeah, that's right; I'm using stateful lambdas. I could lose 4 byes by taking A2 as a `Stack` and using `pop`, but I'm hesitant to stray that far from the `List` interface.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
←←-
```

Takes arrays as input; alternatively, if the arrays are already on the stack, with the second one on the top, it's one character:

```
-
```

Explanation:

```
←        Get first array
 ←       Get second array
  -      Get elementwise difference (as an array)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//UdsEINL9/9/Q1BgA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 27 bytes

```
a=>b=>a::map((n i)=>n-b[i])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY2xDoIwFAB3vuKFOLQGDcWNpJ1cXFxkIyQ8kcoTeRAoUWL8dmxicnfr2ZnbZbV6RW2u2mCadjgIwUBSG95dcyrkuoGsoQk8j3lygGCRqwVeuEBvwWFLfAfX1EA8zA7s2HdwyY6nc0Ca@v1Y4y3cYpim0/AkVwbl/8La1O@6Kj85F99SBsNI7IQVlMeF9FWFlKuKI1DKmwS@SQSHHw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 1 byte

```
_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@////0YYGOgqGhkBsFAvk6CgY6SgYxwIA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 7 bytes

```
L*,BcB_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99HS8cp2Sn@v4tOWmZRcYlCYlFRYqWOgpaVjqGBgqGhgqERl4tOcWpyfl4KVA4kpWCkYMylgqSDK4xLBVkVl0pOYm5SSqKCoZ27XQWX/38A)

Auto vectorisation is so boring.

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](https://www.zsh.org/), 27 bytes

That's right, you can zip arrays in your shell scripts!

**Input**: arrays `a` and `b`
**Output**: stdout

```sh
for x y (${a:^b}) <<<$[x-y]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcjdCoIwGMbx8/cqHmTw5sFgW5/WvJIomLhQEAWN0mLXvpbP0e/5f6Ymvpu28xi9q9G1vb@gHsi/XIfJPyElMvHPGblyI76lDjlVq0zI42MYMWNB@u58r0IOa624znK5xSQu1zHVQ@8j73HAEScUDNbYYQsDzcRFkkxUqRsFDQXFRD8) (It takes more code to read stdin into arrays than it does to pairwise subtract!)

If the output must be another array, either **27** or **29** bytes.

```sh
for x y (${a:^b}) c+=$[x-y]    # if c was declared as an array
for x y (${a:^b}) c+=($[x-y])  # if c was not declared
```

Answer (score 0):

## SmileBASIC, 13 bytes

```
ARYOP 1,A,A,B
```

Inputs: `A`, `B`
Output: `A`

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 3 bytes

```
í-V
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=7S1W&input=WzEwLDExLDEyXQpbMSwyLDNd)

```
í-V     :Implicit input of arrays U & V
í V     :Interleave both
 -      :Reduce each pair by subtraction
```